# Viewport 2/3 empty with 1/3 scaled down

Tags: html, css, windows-mobile, viewport

Why wont the URL http://beta.dealer24x7.com fill the screen on my Windows Phone?

What CSS or META tag am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;
maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```